# How is it that light is reflected in this way in these photos?

Tags: visible-light, reflection

I took 2 photos, in one there's a shutter and in the other there's the light that is reflected from the shutter to the ceiling.
As you know and as you see from the first image, the shutter has alternating empty spaces. However, while at the beginning the light on the ceiling is "correct"(single line), as it extends further it becomes almost an ellipse. Why?
[image]

[image]

Comment: What two surfaces outside are reflecting the light? Is one flat and one curved? This sort of phenomenon has more to do with the local source of light (in this case the reflecting surfaces) than with the shades themselves.

Comment: This looks very like either a double glazed window or a very thick pane: you seem to be seeing reflexions from two surfaces.